# Top 10 Rank for Each Company for Each Month

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, rank

I have a data set that sums the number of pmt_unit by Year, Month, msa and company using a groupby.

I'm hoping to just get the top 10 with the most pmt_units for each company for each month.

This is the code used to get the full ranking list:

```
#For each month for each builder, provide the pmt_units for the top ten cities 
#Group by Month and MSA
SFU_grouped = SFU_2.groupby(['uyear','umonth','msa','stock_ticker']).agg({'pmt_units': 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Sort chronologically, and then by company and rank MSA by pmt_units from most to least. Add a column that ranks msa by pmt_unit for each company

```
SFU_ordered=SFU_grouped.sort_values(['uyear','umonth','company','pmt_units'],
ascending =[True, True, True, False])
SFU_ordered['city_rank']=SFU_ordered.groupby(['company','umonth','uyear'])['pmt_units'].rank(method = 'dense', ascending = False).astype(int)
```

I've tried this

```
SFU_ordered.groupby('company').apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(10,'pmt_units')).reset_index(drop=True)
```

but this just gives me the top ten best highest permit months of all time for each company.

How can I just get the top 10 tank for each company by month?

EDIT: I've clarified the role of the MSA here. Here is a sample table:

[Image of Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqV8M.png)
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqV8M.png)

EDIT: I solved my issue by passing:

```
SFU_year_rank = SFU_year_ordered.set_index('msa').groupby('company')['pmt_units'].nlargest(10).reset_index()
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your DataFrame?

Comment: I tried posting a ASCII sample table but I couldn't get it formatted properly. Will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SFU_ordered['city_rank']=SFU_ordered.groupby(['umonth','company','uyear'])['pmt_units'].rank(method = 'dense', ascending = False).astype(int)`

Comment: Thanks. This gives me the full ranking. I was just hoping for the top 10 for each company for each month. Trying to upload a sample right now for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
    top_n = 10
    top_ten_cities = (SFU_ordered
        .groupby(['umonth','company','uyear'])['pmt_units']
        .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).head(top_n))
```

`head(n)` returns first n rows from a series